# Why does scipy.special.hankel1(0, 10**10) return `nan`?

Tags: python, scipy

```
>>> import scipy.special
>>> scipy.special.hankel1(0, 10**8)
(3.2060295340412074e-05+7.3063911655217044e-05j)
>>> scipy.special.hankel1(0, 10**9)
(2.4687471886269185e-05-5.2104226538976152e-06j)
>>> scipy.special.hankel1(0, 10**10)
(nan+nan*j)
```

I think these examples will work with Mathematica or MATLAB. But I cannot get the correct result from scipy.  I don't know why,  possibly I made some mistake?

Comment: You may be running into a floating point limit, during the calculation of the function. The code is a FORTRAN algorithm, listed [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/special/amos/zbesh.f) (at least, I think this is the one used), which does mention some limitations (though none fit yours). Perhaps file an issue with [scipy](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues?state=open). Note that I can still compute it this way: `np.complex(jv(0, 1e10), yv(0, 1e10))`.

Comment: @Evert How about -3621592938.02? with your method it return (6.210109276541645e-06+nanj)

Comment: Well, I don't say what I suggested is the overall solution; it's just a work-around that works in the 1e10 case. Probably `yv` has a similar problem as `hankel1` when using your new number. I would take it up with the scipy people. Mathematica and matlab are probably running more recent code versions than what scipy uses.

Comment: As a workaround you could use Sympy. Try ``import sympy`` and ``sympy.hankel1(0,10**10).evalf()``.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't consider this a bug, but a feature.

You should enable the error reporting feature by executing

```
scipy.special.errprint(1)
```

Then you will notice:

```
In : scipy.special.hankel1(0, 10**4)
Out: (-0.0070961603533888007+0.0036478055589866053j)

In : scipy.special.hankel1(0, 10**9)
/usr/bin/ipython:1: SpecialFunctionWarning: scipy.special/hankel1:: loss of precision
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out: (2.4687471886269192e-05-5.2104226538976127e-06j)

In : scipy.special.hankel1(0, 10**10)
/usr/bin/ipython:1: SpecialFunctionWarning: scipy.special/hankel1:: no result obtained
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out: (nan+nan*j)
```